# xargs combination of variable and piping

Tags: xargs

Hello I am building a bash script, I would like to use xargs to do a call of `my_command` in parallel, issue is that with the command below, the variable $input_file is not available.

command is looking like:

```
input_file=my_file.txt

awk 'BEGIN{OFS=""} {print $1,":",$2,"-",$3}' data.txt| xargs -P 4 -I {} -n 1 sh -c 'my_command -r {} $input_file > file_per_parameter.txt'
```

How can I access the variable `$input_file` from inside of the command (with keeping `{}` available)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I found out the solution, I just need to export the variable so solution is:
`export input_file=my_file.txt`